# Problems in adjusting width of <a> element within <ul> and <li> and <ol>

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a menu bar for a site, except when I am trying to do it responsive, the width won't adjust to the size of the resposive css. What would be the problem?

This is what i am trying to achieve. Obviously, the elements would be already centered.

[image]

```css
    .categories {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.cat li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ol.type li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
ol.type li a {
    background:var(--dark-grey);
    color: var(--gold);
    padding: 12px 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ol.type li a.active {
    background: var(--gold);
    color:var(--dark-grey);
}
ol.type li a:hover {
    background: var(--gold);
    color:var(--dark-grey);
}

.type{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

:root{
    --gold: #bfa75d;
    --black: black;
    --dark-grey:#303030;
    --light-grey:#c4c4c4;
    --medium-grey: #c9c9c9;
    --white: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
        <ul class="cat">
          <li>
            <ol class="type">
              <li><a data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>
              <li><a data-filter=".web">Web Design</a></li>
              <li><a data-filter=".webapp">Web Apps</a></li>
              <li><a data-filter=".graphic">Graphic Design</a></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Just use `min-width` property in `li` of your size to make all of them equal in width and make `<a>` tag a `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the ol.type li a to block in order for them to all be the same size, then change flex-direction of .type to be column instead of row. Make sure you add this to the bottom of your css because its a media query.

```
@media (max-width:700px)
{
    ol.type li a {
        display: block !important;
    }

    .type {
        flex-direction:column !important;
    }
}
```